# Arduino myFile.write(buff, len) don't work

Tags: c, arduino, arduino-uno

I recently writing some code about taking IMU data and save it to SD card. To increase the speed of writing data, I need to using binary format to save it, here is my code:

```
byte myData[20];

((long int*)myData)[0] = count;
((long int*)myData)[4] = microSec;
((short int*)myData)[8] = ax;
((short int*)myData)[10] = ay;
((short int*)myData)[12] = az;
((short int*)myData)[14] = gx;
((short int*)myData)[16] = gy;
((short int*)myData)[18] = gz;

myFile3.write(myData, sizeof(myData));
```

but it's totally not working.(but it's ok to compile, that's really confuse me...)

Does anyone meet this problem...?

Comment: the problem is that `((long int*)myData)[4]` actually corresponds to myData[12] ~ myData[15], and so on, which, i guess, is not what you want

Comment: `((short int*)myData)[8]` corresponds to myData[16] ~ myData[17], etc.

Comment: Why in the world would you do this instead of declaring a struct? The field order is even correctly packed already.

Comment: @hobbs probably he wants to avoid waste of bytes due to padding. although i guess bit fields would be a neater way of doing this

Comment: @mangusta that's what I'm saying though, there would be no padding in this case (even if there was, you could use `__attribute__((packed))` to deal with it, but as it is every field is already aligned so no padding is needed).

Comment: just use a struct. Bitfield is not even needed

Comment: I declared the struct before....but the code with struct even can't compile successfully but this code. QQ

Comment: It shows error message: "File::write(data_t&, unsigned int)'"

Comment: Try with `*((long int *)(myData + 0)) = count; *((long int *)(myData + 4)) = microSec;` and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys! The problem is solved with hundreds tests (lack of C coding skill level really bothers me on Arduino coding...)

Here is new code (edit by @frarugi87 's suggestion)

```
byte myData[20];
  *((long int *)(myData+0)) = count;
  *((long int *)(myData+4)) = microSec;
  *((short int *)(myData+8)) = ax;
  *((short int *)(myData+10)) = ay;
  *((short int *)(myData+12)) = az;
  *((short int *)(myData+14)) = gx;
  *((short int *)(myData+16)) = gy;
  *((short int *)(myData+18)) = gz;
```

it's really works and Data is right, for example

data: 0C 6A 30 00

answer : 3172876

and I also find another way to do it:

```
  myFile3.write( (byte*)&count, sizeof(long));
  myFile3.write( (byte*)&microSec, sizeof(long));
  myFile3.write( (byte*)&ax, sizeof(short));
  myFile3.write( (byte*)&ay, sizeof(short));
  myFile3.write( (byte*)&az, sizeof(short));
  myFile3.write( (byte*)&gx, sizeof(short));
  myFile3.write( (byte*)&gy, sizeof(short));
  myFile3.write( (byte*)&gz, sizeof(short));
```

it works too and the data format is same as the first coding way.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

how about trying this:

```
    byte myData[20];

((long int*)myData)[0] = count;
((long int*)myData)[1] = microSec;
((short int*)myData)[4] = ax;
((short int*)myData)[5] = ay;
((short int*)myData)[6] = az;
((short int*)myData)[7] = gx;
((short int*)myData)[8] = gy;
((short int*)myData)[9] = gz;

myFile3.write(myData, sizeof(myData));
```

Comment: @詹智翔 could you post the contents of `myData` array and the output you get (the wrong one) ?